# Oracle calculate 2 date columns to a new one for each row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

in our Application we have two columns at the moment. 1 column with the datetime of an event and 1 column with the datetime how much earlier the alarm should go off. Now we have a new one and thats the exact datetime when the alarm goes off.

I know how I can calculate this for only 1 row, but not for all

```
select to_date('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + (select termin_start - alarmvorlauf from termine where id = 1013) from dual
```

How can I modify the sql so it can update every row in the table 'termine'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand you, but my guess:

```
UPDATE termine SET alarm_goes_off = (to_date('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + (termin_start - alarmvorlauf));
```

Please add more detail if this is not what you need.